# Cannot display embedded array of react components

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have the following situation :

I have a parent component that wants to display an array of child components (3 to be exact..). However the "arrayOfComponents" does not display when I render ParentComponent.

The code looks like this :

```
let arrayOfComponents =
    [1,2,3].map(() => {
        return (props) => <div>TEST {props.position}</div>
    })

let ParentComponent = () => {
    return <>
        <div>Show Me Three Elements</div>
        <div>the length of array is {arrayOfComponents && arrayOfComponents.length} </div>
        <div>
        {arrayOfComponents && arrayOfComponents.map((e, i) => {
            return <div><e position={i}/></div>
        })}
        </div>
    </>
}
```

I expected :

```
Show Me Three Elements
the length of array is 3
TEST 1
TEST 2
TEST 3
```

but instead I get

```
Show Me Three Elements
the length of array is 3
```

I assumed that you can just display each element in the array in JSX form like so :

```
<e position={i}/>
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

you can define `arrayOfComponents` as an array of numbers `[1,2,3]` and inside the `ParentComponent`  you can put a map loop like this

```
{arrayOfComponents && arrayOfComponents.map((value, i) => {
            return (<div>TEST {value}</div>)
})}
```

no need to complicate things i think this is the best approach for it

Comment: yes i know you can do that, but i actually have a dynamic array of components which can have their properties set. I simplified this just for illustrative purposes.